# Apache NiFi - RouteOnAttribute expressions and logging

Tags: expression, apache-nifi

I'm very new to Apache NiFi and I just wanted to try out a small transformation.

This is my file,

```
product,quantity,identity,cost
apple,10,A,2323
laptop,24,I,1332
tablet,33,B,33121
```

I want to look for the identity column and if I have 'I', then that row should be rejected the others should be accepted.

I get the file using GetFile processor, and connect to RouteOnAttribute and this is how I have configured my property,

[image]

I then connect to

> a. LogAttribute for unmatched, I value and then to a PutFile to an error folder.
> b. PutFile from RouteOnAttribute on identity to an output folder

I always get the full file in the error folder, it is not rejecting the row based on the expression.

Since I'm very new to this expression languages, I cannot understand if it is really working or not. I need to see what are the expression results? I cannot find anything in the nifi-app.log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Whomever given - rating, would be nice if you provide the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `QueryRecord` [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html):

- `Record Reader`: `CSVReader`
- `Record Writer`: `CSVRecordSetWriter`
- `i-match` (dynamic property): `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE "identity"='I'`
- `identity` (dynamic property): `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE "identity"<>'I'`

Input (CSV):

```
product,quantity,identity,cost
apple,10,A,2323
laptop,24,I,1332
tablet,33,B,33121
```

Output (i-match):

```
product,quantity,identity,cost
laptop,24,I,1332
```

Output (identity):

```
product,quantity,identity,cost
apple,10,A,2323
tablet,33,B,33121
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I need some help on logging the NiFi process at each level, I have tried LogOnAttribute but it doesnt works as expected. Also need help on consumekafka with nifi.